# Will libpcap based sniffer work for dial-up based internet connections

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I am writing an http-sniffer using libpcap. I wonder will it work, if user uses a dial-up based internet connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Dial-up connections will appear as a separate interface on the computer (in most cases, anyway), and can be sniffed normally.

Comment: Note, however, that you must *NOT* assume that packets are Ethernet packets - *all* programs using libpcap/WinPcap should call `pcap_datalink()` to determine the link-layer header type for the captured packets and dissect them based on the returned value.  See the "corresponding DLT_ name" values and descriptions in the [list of link-layer header type values](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html).